# Signed and unsigned representation

Tags: unsigned, signed

What would the decimal number be of this word of 32 bits 1011 0010 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 if unsigned representation and signed magnitude representation have been used?

Answer (score 0):

For getting negative value need invert all the bits through the number and add one.
See:

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int Bin2Dec(const char *cs){
    unsigned int  r=0;
    for ( r=0;*cs; ++cs) {
        switch (*cs) {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
        r = (r << 1) | ( *cs - '0');
    }
    return r;
}
void PrintBin(unsigned int n) {
    int i;
    printf("%12d  :  ",n);
    for (i=31; i >=0; --i) {
        int b=((1<<i) & n) >> i;
        printf(" %u",b);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main() {
    unsigned int  u= Bin2Dec("1011 0010 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000");
    printf("unsigned  is %u  ,  signed  is %d\n",u, u);
    PrintBin(u); // For test
    u=~u + 1; // Invert all the bits through the number and add one
    printf("%u     %d\n",u, u);
    PrintBin(u);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

unsigned  is 2991587328  ,  signed  is -1303379968
 -1303379968  :   1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1303379968     1303379968
  1303379968  :   0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0